# Create Python bytecode from list of opcodes and arguments?

Tags: python, bytecode

Is there an easy way to create Python bytecode from a list of 2-tuples with opcodes and their arguments?

For instance:

```
>>> bytecode_compile([
        ('LOAD_CONST', 2),
        ('STORE_FAST', 'a'),
        ('LOAD_FAST', 'a'),
        ('RETURN_VALUE',)])
'd\x01\x00}\x00\x00|\x00\x00S'
```

Comment: What's wrong with writing Python code and using the Python compiler to do this?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/byteplay/

Comment: @S.Lott Fair enough. Not sure why I'm trying to make things so difficult.

Comment: "Not sure why I'm trying to make things so difficult".  If you can't explain why, then perhaps we should close this question.

Comment: This translates to `a = 2; return a;`

Answer (score 4):

I wrote at length about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348067/modifying-python-bytecode/40105522#40105522) so I won't repeat that but will give some summary comments.

It is definitely doable, but I wonder how generally useful it will be. The link goes into how to run and write out such stuff.

Bytecode is subject to change both in terms of opcode, or opcode names, or semantics of the opcodes between versions. In fact, in Python 3.6 and beyond a bytecode becomes a wordcode.

If you however do decide to go down this path [xdis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xdis) recently added a `list2bytecode()` function to do just this.

If you prefer to work in a text file as most assembly code is written, I wrote [xasm](https://github.com/rocky/python-xasm) for this. Here is some sample assembly in the format that this can use:

```
# Python bytecode 3.6 (3379)

# Method Name:       five
# Filename:          /tmp/five.pl
# Argument count:    0
# Kw-only arguments: 0
# Number of locals:  0
# Stack size:        1
# Flags:             0x00000043 (NOFREE | NEWLOCALS | OPTIMIZED)
# First Line:        1
# Constants:
#    0: None
#    1: 5
  2:
            LOAD_CONST           (5)
            RETURN_VALUE


# Method Name:       <module>
# Filename:          /tmp/five.pl
# Argument count:    0
# Kw-only arguments: 0
# Number of locals:  0
# Stack size:        2
# Flags:             0x00000040 (NOFREE)
# First Line:        1
# Constants:
#    0: <code object five at 0x0000>
#    1: 'five'
#    2: None
# Names:
#    0: five
#    1: print
  1:
            LOAD_CONST           0 (<code object five at 0x0000>)
            LOAD_CONST           ('five')
            MAKE_FUNCTION        0
            STORE_NAME           (five)

  3:
            LOAD_NAME            (print)
            LOAD_NAME            (five)
            CALL_FUNCTION        0
            CALL_FUNCTION        1
            POP_TOP
            LOAD_CONST           (None)
            RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: You should add a disclaimer informing that you wrote `xasm`

Comment: @Rightleg updated. If that doesn't do it for you, suggest an edit.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a Python "bytecode assembly" assembler exists, but it might not be that hard to build one yourself.  In the python source code in **Python-X.Y.Z/Include/opcode.h**, all of the bytecodes for the opcodes are listed with what arguments they take.

Comment: You can also get similar list with `dis` module, f.e. `len(dis.opmap)` returns 101 against 103 opcodes in `opcode.h` of Python 3.4.3.