# modifying python bytecode

Tags: python, bytecode

I was wondering how to modify byte code, then recompile that code so I can use it in python as a function?  I've been trying:

```
a = """
def fact():
    a = 8
    a = 0
"""
c = compile(a, '<string>', 'exec')
w = c.co_consts[0].co_code
dis(w)
```

which decompiles to:

```
      0 LOAD_CONST          1 (1)
      3 STORE_FAST          1 (1)
      6 LOAD_CONST          2 (2)
      9 STORE_FAST          1 (1)
     12 LOAD_CONST          0 (0)
     15 RETURN_VALUE
```

supposing I want to get rid of lines 0 and 3, I call:

```
x = c.co_consts[0].co_code[6:16]
dis(x)
```

which results in :

```
      0 LOAD_CONST          2 (2)
      3 STORE_FAST          1 (1)
      6 LOAD_CONST          0 (0)
      9 RETURN_VALUE
```

my problem is what to do with `x`, if I try `exec x` I get an 'expected string without nullbytes and I get the same for `exec w`, 
trying to compile `x` results in: compile() expected string without null bytes.

I'm not sure what the best way to proceed, except maybe I need to create some kind of code-object, but I'm not sure how, but I'm assuming it must be
possible aka byteplay, python assemblers et al

I'm using python 2.7.10, but I'd like it to be future compatible (Eg python 3) if it's possible.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would do this, what is your use case?

Comment: Python bytecode is considered an implementation detail and can change from version to version and interpreter to interpreter. There's no documentation except the interpreter source. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: @shuttle87, I'm writing a game engine with scripts which I'm hoping to write in python, but I want to run some optimisations on the scripts bytecode which loosely speaking won't be known in advance (although the basic structure will be known as they all share a common base class). I've got all the other components working, just this converting bytecode to a usable function is the last hurdle.

Comment: @antimony - yes I'm sure but can't say I relish the idea of digging through a bunch of c code, any other methods?

Comment: @BitmapImage sound like it could be a case of premature optimization to me. Check that you actually need the extra performance and that this is a bottleneck. You might want to try using pypy first before hacking around with bytecode, the pypy's JIT might be good enough for your uses.

Comment: @shuttle87, ive been checking out byteplay source and I believe at least part of the answer lies within its source code, I found at line 780 types.codetype(blah) which looks like the kind of thing I was looking for, so now I'm gonna try and implement my own custom version

Answer (score 23):

*Update: For sundry reasons I have started writing a Cross-Python-version assembler. See https://github.com/rocky/python-xasm. It is still in very early beta. See also [bytecode](https://bytecode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).*

As far as I know there is no other *currently-maintained* Python assembler. [PEAK's Bytecode Disassembler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BytecodeAssembler) was developed for Python 2.6, and later modified to support early Python 2.7.

It is pretty cool from the [documentation](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/BytecodeAssembler#toc). But it relies on other PEAK libraries which might be problematic.

I'll go through the whole example to give you a feel for what you'd have to do. It is not pretty, but then you should expect that.

Basically after modifying the bytecode, you need to create a new [`types.CodeType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html?highlight=codetype#types.CodeType) object. You need a new one because many of the objects in the code type, for good reason,  you can't change. For example the interpreter may have some of these object values cached.

After creating code, you can use this in functions that use a code type which can be used in `exec` or `eval`.

Or you can write this to a bytecode file. Alas the code format has changed between Python versions 1.3, 1,5, 2.0, 3.0, 3.8, and 3.10. And by the way so has the optimization and bytecodes. In fact, in Python 3.6 they will be *word* codes not bytecodes.

So here is what you'd have to do for your example:

```
a = """
def fact():
    a = 8
    a = 0
    return a
"""
c = compile(a, '<string>', 'exec')
fn_code = c.co_consts[0] # Pick up the function code from the main code
from dis import dis
dis(fn_code)
print("=" * 30)

x = fn_code.co_code[6:16] # modify bytecode

import types
opt_fn_code = types.CodeType(fn_code.co_argcount,
                             # c.co_kwonlyargcount,  Add this in Python3
                             # c.co_posonlyargcount, Add this in Python 3.8+
                             fn_code.co_nlocals,
                             fn_code.co_stacksize,
                             fn_code.co_flags,
                             x,  # fn_code.co_code: this you changed
                             fn_code.co_consts,
                             fn_code.co_names,
                             fn_code.co_varnames,
                             fn_code.co_filename,
                             fn_code.co_name,
                             fn_code.co_firstlineno,
                             fn_code.co_lnotab,   # In general, You should adjust this
                             fn_code.co_freevars,
                             fn_code.co_cellvars)
dis(opt_fn_code)
print("=" * 30)
print("Result is", eval(opt_fn_code))

# Now let's change the value of what's returned
co_consts = list(opt_fn_code.co_consts)
co_consts[-1] = 10

opt_fn_code = types.CodeType(fn_code.co_argcount,
                             # c.co_kwonlyargcount,  Add this in Python3
                             # c.co_posonlyargcount, Add this in Python 3.8+
                             fn_code.co_nlocals,
                             fn_code.co_stacksize,
                             fn_code.co_flags,
                             x,  # fn_code.co_code: this you changed
                             tuple(co_consts), # this is now changed too
                             fn_code.co_names,
                             fn_code.co_varnames,
                             fn_code.co_filename,
                             fn_code.co_name,
                             fn_code.co_firstlineno,
                             fn_code.co_lnotab,   # In general, You should adjust this
                             fn_code.co_freevars,
                             fn_code.co_cellvars)

dis(opt_fn_code)
print("=" * 30)
print("Result is now", eval(opt_fn_code))
```

When I ran this here is what I got:

```
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (8)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  4           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  5          12 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
==============================
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  4           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
==============================
('Result is', 0)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  4           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
==============================
('Result is now', 10)
```

Notice that the line numbers haven't changed even though I removed in code a couple of lines. That is because I didn't update `fn_code.co_lnotab`.

If you want to now write a Python bytecode file from this. Here is what you'd do:

```
co_consts = list(c.co_consts)
co_consts[0] = opt_fn_code
c1 = types.CodeType(c.co_argcount,
                    # c.co_posonlyargcount, Add this in Python 3.8+
                    # c.co_kwonlyargcount,  Add this in Python3
                    c.co_nlocals,
                    c.co_stacksize,
                    c.co_flags,
                    c.co_code,
                    tuple(co_consts),
                    c.co_names,
                    c.co_varnames,
                    c.co_filename,
                    c.co_name,
                    c.co_firstlineno,
                    c.co_lnotab,   # In general, You should adjust this
                    c.co_freevars,
                    c.co_cellvars)

from struct import pack
with open('/tmp/testing.pyc', 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(pack('Hcc', 62211, '\r', '\n')) # Python 2.7 magic number
        import time
        fp.write(pack('I', int(time.time())))
        # In Python 3.7+ you need to PEP 552 bits 
        # In Python 3 you need to write out the size mod 2**32 here
        import marshal
        fp.write(marshal.dumps(c1))
```

To simplify writing the boilerplate bytecode above, I've added a routine to [xasm](https://github.com/rocky/python-xasm) called *write_pycfile()*.

Now to check the results:

```
$ uncompyle6 /tmp/testing.pyc
# uncompyle6 version 2.9.2
# Python bytecode 2.7 (62211)
# Disassembled from: Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul 26 2016, 22:53:31)
# [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
# Embedded file name: <string>
# Compiled at: 2016-10-18 05:52:13


def fact():
    a = 0
# okay decompiling /tmp/testing.pyc
$ pydisasm /tmp/testing.pyc
# pydisasm version 3.1.0
# Python bytecode 2.7 (62211) disassembled from Python 2.7
# Timestamp in code: 2016-10-18 05:52:13
# Method Name:       <module>
# Filename:          <string>
# Argument count:    0
# Number of locals:  0
# Stack size:        1
# Flags:             0x00000040 (NOFREE)
# Constants:
#    0: <code object fact at 0x7f815843e4b0, file "<string>", line 2>
#    1: None
# Names:
#    0: fact
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object fact at 0x7f815843e4b0, file "<string>", line 2>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (fact)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE


# Method Name:       fact
# Filename:          <string>
# Argument count:    0
# Number of locals:  1
# Stack size:        1
# Flags:             0x00000043 (NOFREE | NEWLOCALS | OPTIMIZED)
# Constants:
#    0: None
#    1: 8
#    2: 10
# Local variables:
#    0: a
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  4           6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
$
```

An alternate approach for optimization is to optimize at the [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#module-ast) level (AST). The `compile`, `eval` and `exec` functions can start from an AST, or you can dump the AST. You could also write this back out as Python source using the Python module astor

Note however that some kinds of optimization like tail-recursion elimination might leave bytecode in a form that it can't be transformed in a truly faithful way to source code. See [my pycon2018 Columbia Lightning Talk](http://rocky.github.io/pycon2018-light.co/#/) for a video I made which eliminates tail recursion in bytecode to get an idea of what I'm talking about here.

If you want to be able to debug and single step bytecode instructions. See my [bytecode interpreter](https://pypi.org/project/x-python/) and its [bytecode debugger](https://pypi.org/project/trepanxpy/).