# ipdb list command not work after step into function

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, ipdb

I was debugging using ipdb and use step command to step into a function in a another file. And then list command not work anymore. Below is output from debuggin. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
> parse.py(36)<module>()
     35 import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
---> 36 model.fit(observations, obsrv_lengths)
     37 f.close()

ipdb> list
     31 
     32 observations = np.concatenate(observations)
     33 
     34 model = hmm.MultinomialHMM(n_components=20, n_iter=50)
     35 import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
---> 36 model.fit(observations, obsrv_lengths)
     37 f.close()
     38 
     39 f2 = open('training.log')
     40 for line in f2:
     41     sql = line.split('\n')[0].split('Query')

ipdb> s
--Call--
> hmmlearn/base.py(398)fit()

ipdb> list

ipdb>
```

Comment: can you view the contents of `hmmlearn/base.py` in general (in another editor)?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote at great length about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648163/python-ipdb-occasionally-shows-no-code-lines?answertab=active#tab-top).

The basic idea is that there might not be a source file to show, and ipdb and pdb are pretty weak when that happens. You can use `bt` to get some idea of why this might be happening, and use [trepan](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan/) to sometimes overcome it.