# Create empty set in one instruction from disassembly

Tags: python, optimization

It is well known that python has no empty set literal. However, I would like to know if there is still a performant way of creating an empty set

these are a few other ways to create an empty set...

There is the pythonic way:

```py
def f():
    return set()
```

There is also this nasty looking way by unpacking an empty tuple:

```py
def g():
    return {*()}
```

You could also build a set with one item and then remove that item:

```py
def h()
    s = {1}
    s.remove(1)
    return s
```

Trying to use the literal syntax to create a set will give you a dictionary:

```py
def i()
    return {}
```

Interestingly, the results of `dis` for each function (Python 3) are as follows:

```
>>> dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (set)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(g)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (())
              2 BUILD_SET_UNPACK         1
              4 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(h)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 BUILD_SET                1
              4 STORE_FAST               0 (s)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
              8 LOAD_METHOD              0 (remove)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             12 CALL_METHOD              1
             14 POP_TOP

  4          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(i)
  2           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Looking at the disassemby, the pythonic way (function `f`) requires two instructions, first a `LOAD_GLOBAL` (which can be converted to a `LOAD_FAST` if you provide `set` as an argument with default value of `set`), and then the function call.

Creating a `dict` takes only one instruction, `BUILD_MAP`.

I can see from `h` that the set comprehension uses an equivalent instruction to `BUILD_MAP`, `BUILD_SET`, except that it first loads the constant value of (1) into the stack.

Is there a way to get Python to generate the bytecode `BUILD_SET` with no elements in the stack, like how the dict comprehension generated `BUILD_MAP` in function `i`?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve where it matters whether `set()` uses 1 or 2 bytecode instructions?

Comment: It's not possible, since there's no "empty set" literal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty set literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130374/empty-set-literal)

Comment: Maybe [modifying python bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33348067)?

Comment: There is no empty set literal, if that is what you are asking. This seems like much ado about nothing. In any case, byte code is purely an implementation detail. It can (and often does) change, minor version to minor version.

Comment: Note, in the original PEP 218 that added a built-in set object, the notation `{-}` was proposed for an empty set, but actually, set literals did not get added at all at the time, I believe.

Comment: the question is not looking for a nice pythonic set literal (but it would be nice if there was one), the reason for asking is that having a single instruction is most likely to be the most performant way of creating an empty set

Comment: @mkrieger1 make an empty set as fast as possible, it's as simple as that